# How to update tkinter text label after updating current work directory with file

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, user-interface, tkinter

I have a button that asks the user to select a directory and a function that stores this path in a varibale `pwd`.  After selecting a directory, I'd like to display the path and have it updated anytime the users clicks on the button and selects a new directory.

How do I get the text label to update or refresh everytime the function gets a new path?

```py
import os
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

#Set working directory for GUI
def work_dir():
    pwd = filedialog.askdirectory()
    os.chdir(pwd)

window = Tk()

btn_getPWD = Button(text="Change Work Directory", command = work_dir)
btn_getPWD.pack()

cwd = Label(window, text = "Current Working Directory: " + os.getcwd())
cwd.pack(anchor="w")
```

Comment: You can set a row and column for the label, like i have done here, it shows a file and if i change file it shows path to that file.
`l0=Label(wins,text='showing file ' + filename,bg='black',fg='yellow').grid(column=2,row=1)`

Comment: Just update the text of the label `cwd` inside `work_dir()` function.

Comment: @acw1668 How do I update `work_dir()` to make this work?  I've also changed `os.getcwd()` to `pwd` but nothing shows up (makes sense since the function doesn't run until I click the button).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is so hard in this? Use `config()` to update the text inside the function:

```
def work_dir():
    pwd = filedialog.askdirectory()
    os.chdir(pwd)
    cwd.config(text="Current Working Directory: " + pwd)
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked!  Do you have any resources you can point me to to learn more about tkinter? I'm still new to python.

Comment: @Peter Check [this](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/tkinter.pdf) out